# LEN() & CHARINDEX() problem in formatting field

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following query:

```
UPDATE P
SET Street = TRIM(LEFT(FormattedAddress, CHARINDEX(',', FormattedAddress)-1)),
    Town = TRIM(RIGHT(FormattedAddress, LEN(FormattedAddress)-CHARINDEX(',', FormattedAddress)))
FROM Person P
```

and it's suddenly started failing with the following error:

> Msg 537, Level 16, State 2, Line 3
>
> Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.
> The statement has been terminated.

How could I find the data that is causing this to fail and fix the update statement so it doesn't fail in the future?

Comment: That all depends on what you would like to happen if `FormattedAddress` does not contain `,`, which is what triggers the error. (Note that trying to parse addresses is [problematic in general anyway](https://www.mjt.me.uk/posts/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-addresses/).)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How could I find the data that is causing this to fail and fix the
>   update statement so it doesn't fail in the future?

Try like this to find. You will get the rows which are breaking your query.

```
SELECT * FROM
Person P
WHERE CHARINDEX(',', FormattedAddress) <=0
```

Better way of writing same query as suggested by  **Jeroen Mostert**  is like following.

```
SELECT * FROM
Person P
WHERE FormattedAddress NOT LIKE '%,%'
```

Comment: That's a very complicated and redundant way of writing `WHERE FormattedAddress NOT LIKE '%,%'`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this @JeroenMostert. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks PSK, is there a way to get the UPDATE statement to take that into account. If I add WHERE FormattedAddress NOT LIKE '%,%' I now get Msg 536, Level 16, State 2, Line 3
Invalid length parameter passed to the RIGHT function.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: NOT LIKE '%,%' will throw the error for sure, I wrote query to return rows which will break your update. You need to exclude such records so put WHERE FormattedAddress LIKE '%,%'

Comment: Thanks @PSK, that has done the trick and adding that to the bottom of my update query meaning I haven't needed to change the functionality of it at all and risk breaking it.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the Error because there are values in FormattedAddress which do not have a "," and hence the `CHARINDEX` function will return the value as 0 for those. since for `LEFT`,`RIGHT` and `SUBSTRING` functions accept only positive integers greater than 0, These rows will throw an Error.

You can easily identify the rows that are causing the issue using the following query

```
SELECT
    *
    FROM Person P
        WHERE CHARINDEX(',', FormattedAddress) = 0
```

There are multiple ways you can overcome the same

**Approach# 1**

Use Case inside the `LEFT` / `RIGHT`

```
UPDATE P
SET
    Street = TRIM(LEFT(FormattedAddress, 
                            CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(',', FormattedAddress)>1
                                    THEN CHARINDEX(',', FormattedAddress)-1
                                ELSE LEN(FormattedAddress) END)
                                ),
    Town = TRIM(RIGHT(FormattedAddress, 
                                CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(',', FormattedAddress)>0
                                        THEN LEN(FormattedAddress)-CHARINDEX(',', FormattedAddress)
                                    ELSE LEN(FormattedAddress) END)
                                    )
    FROM Person P
```

**Approach# 2**

Filter the records in the `WHERE` clause

```
UPDATE P
SET
    Street = TRIM(LEFT(FormattedAddress, CHARINDEX(',', FormattedAddress)-1)),
    Town = TRIM(RIGHT(FormattedAddress, LEN(FormattedAddress)-CHARINDEX(',', FormattedAddress)))
    FROM Person P
        WHERE CHARINDEX(',', FormattedAddress) > 1
```

Comment: From comments to the other answers, there seems to be cases where FormattedAddress's LEN returns 0 - meaning it's either an empty string or whichspaces only. This should also be covered.

Comment: Approach #1 is syntactically invalid; check your parentheses. Even after fixing it, it will set both `Street` and `Town` equal to `FormattedAddress` if there's no `,`. This is probably not desirable (although, technically, the OP has not said what should happen). It's even worse if `FormattedAddress` starts with `,`.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I've updated and fixed the issue with Approach# 1

Answer (score 0):

You can use `WHERE` cease :

```
WHERE FormattedAddress LIKE '%,%'
```

However, you can also do :

```
UPDATE P
     SET Street = TRIM(LEFT(FormattedAddress, CHARINDEX(',', FormattedAddress + ',')-1)),
     Town = TRIM(RIGHT(FormattedAddress, LEN(FormattedAddress)-CHARINDEX(',', FormattedAddress)))
FROM Person P;
```

Comment: Thanks, but gives the following error now:

Msg 536, Level 16, State 2, Line 3
Invalid length parameter passed to the RIGHT function.
The statement has been terminated.